# Windows System Administration - videos or pod casts

Tags: windows, video, podcast

I am looking for podcast or videos on  Windows System Administration

Ideally they should cover the basics & the more advanced topics

Comment: See question 3765 "What good Sysadmin podcasts are out there?"

Answer (score 7):

Richard Campbell and Greg Hughes host [RunAs Radio](http://www.runasradio.com/), a weekly Internet Audio Talk Show for IT Professionals working with Microsoft products.

They [talked to Jeff Attwood](http://www.runasradio.com/default.aspx?showNum=109) recently about ServerFault.

Answer (score 4):

Though it's not really a technical podcast, I like [Windows Weekly](http://twit.tv/ww) for getting interesting information on upcoming developments on the Windows platform, and it's pretty entertaining IMHO. Have the balance out the dry stuff with some enjoyable shows too..

Comment: I enjoy Paul's podcast as well. It's too bad it's the only one he does.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if your looking to pay for them, but the [CBT Nuggets](http://www.cbtnuggets.com/) range are excellent videos on a range of windows system administration topics, helped me through my MCSE. They do offer a range of free videos as well as paid for ones.

Answer (score 3):

The [Mind of Root](http://www.mindofroot.com/) Podcast is pretty good.

They've been around for awhile (now up to show 98).  I've been listening to past shows and usually come away with a couple of ideas or solutions/products I hadn't heard of.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye on itcookbook.net ... not much happening there right now. But it's coming!

Answer (score 1):

[Webcasts on Technet](http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/technetmms.aspx?tab=webcasts) usually provides videos from all the latest conferences. The linked latest event with a bunch of webcasts from seems to be called "Managing a Microsoft Infrastructure" - how fitting ^^

Answer (score 1):

**Citrix Metaframe** expert Brian Madden used to podcast (really good), but he wound up some time in 2007, around the time of NetScaler but before XenServer. However, he seems to have replaced the podcast with a video channel, [Brian Madden TV](http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/tv/default.aspx). If you're publishing content over Citrix products or big on Terminal Server this could be useful.

For network security and compliance issues check out [RISKY.BIZ](http://risky.biz/) and their podcasts [Risky Business](http://risky.biz/netcasts/risky-business) and the interview/event feed, [RB2](http://risky.biz/netcasts/rb2).

**Virtual Strategy Magazine** has a [podcast](http://www.virtual-strategy.com/all-podcasts) of interest to admins working in virtualized environments.

Answer (score 1):

[CSTechCast](http://www.cstechcast.com/) is a great show and they have great interviews, and good news content and tips.

Answer (score 1):

[TechNet Events and Webcasts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/events/default.aspx) has some great webcasts and podcasts available. No subscription to technet required.  In addition Microsoft provides various virtual machines and lab guides available to get some hands on time for servers or subjects you don't have time to build a lab for.  The virtual labs are available here: [TechNet Virtual Labs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft had their [Technet Radio](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb510143.aspx) which was podcasts about their various products.  They talk about  their history, present, and future and the best practices around them.  I say had because it has been a couple months since they published any new posts so I don't know if they stopped making any new episodes.

If your a VMware administrator, then I recommend these podcasts:

- [VMware Communities Roundtable](http://www.talkshoe.com/talkshoe/web/talkCast.jsp?masterId=19367)
- [Virtualization Security Roundtable](http://www.talkshoe.com/talkshoe/web/talkCast.jsp?masterId=34217&cmd=tc)
- [Virtual Thoughts](http://www.talkshoe.com/talkshoe/web/talkCast.jsp?masterId=50667&cmd=tc)

If your into Powershell then I recommend these

- [Powerscripting podcast](http://powerscripting.wordpress.com/)
- [get-scripting podcast](http://get-scripting.blogspot.com/)

and the following three are really developer podcasts but they sometimes lean towards system administration and really good shows:

- [StackOverflow podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/)
- [Hanselminutes](http://www.hanselminutes.com/)
- [Sod This](http://www.sodthis.com/podcast/)

and if your into great conspiracy theories in regards to IT => 
[I, Cringley](http://www.cringely.com/)

I'm also fans of the previously mentioned [RunAs Radio](http://www.runasradio.com/), [Brian Madden TV](http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/tv/default.aspx), and [Mind of Root](http://www.mindofroot.com/)