# Podcasts/Technical Audio Books

Tags: security, podcast

I recently changed jobs and I now have a decent commute to work. I am looking at getting my CISSP/random GIAC certs but I am having a hard time trying to find time to read and study. I was wondering if there are any good technical audio books on Information Security. I am also listening to Security Now and PaulDotCom podcasts but if anyone has a better recommendation I would love to hear it. Thank you very much.

Comment: See: 
http://serverfault.com/questions/7536/
http://serverfault.com/questions/7006/
http://serverfault.com/questions/3765/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are able to ignore Leo Laporte when he gets annoying, I reccomend most of the podcasts in the [TWiT network](http://twit.tv/), including [Security Now!](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm). There are other more or less technical podcasts worth have a look at, including [Digital Planet](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/science/2009/03/000000_digital_planet.shtml) (BBC) and [Tech Weekly](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/series/techweekly) (The Guardian).

All in all, just go through the technology section of iTunes or your favourite podcast aggregator. You'll quickly filter out the poor stuff, and find the ones you really like.

As for technical audio books.. well, I hear the new kindle can read aloud.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the information. I was just really hoping there would be some audio book out there.